# C# Excel worksheet doesn't format cells

Tags: c#, excel, format, export

I want to export a table on a website (Silverlight) to an excel worksheet. The export itself works without any problems, **but** I can't set the format for the cells.
This is my code:

```
if (row.ElementAt(i - 1).Value == null) 
{
    excelWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, colIndex].Value = "";
}
else 
{
    excelWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, colIndex].Value = row.ElementAt(i - 1).Value.ToString();

    switch (row.ElementAt(i - 1).Key)
    {
         case "AE":
             //excelWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, colIndex].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,###,###.00 €";
             excelWorksheet.SelectedRange[rowCount, colIndex].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,###,###.00 €";
             break;
         default:
             break;
    }
}
```

`row.ElementAt(i - 1).Key` is holding the name of the column, which I need for the switch-case, because I just want to format specific cells.

Both these lines aren't working.

`excelWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, colIndex].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,###,###.00 €";`
`excelWorksheet.SelectedRange[rowCount, colIndex].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,###,###.00 €";`

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it now!

It didn't work because you need to set the cell's value **AFTER** you set the format.